# Bootstrap 4 Gallery - Horizontal Card Layout

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to design a gallery with square elements of varying widths. I want the squares to fill free slots/space. I have seen this working using Bootstrap cards, however, I could only get this to work with verying heights.

Any tips?

This is an example of what I'd like to achieve:
[image]

The proposed answer does not answer this question as it explicitely states that all divs have the same width which is not the case here.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: what you have tried ? 
Provide your html and css please.

Comment: Right now, it's only a row with col-md-6/col-md-3 columns. I've looked into something like the following, but that only seems to work for varying heights: https://www.codeply.com/go/q03ZHDeSGN